# At what speed does a diskworld need to be spun to counteract horizontal gravity?

Tags: planets, gravity

I am trying to build a disk world and trying to find out how fast it needs to spin to counteract the horizontal component of the gravitational field. I dont know how the gravitational field varies across the surface (the calculation is above me); I'm assuming that it doesn't vary proportionally with **r** like the centrifugal force, so a perfect cancellation is not possible. In that case, I would like to know the optimum speed required. Moreover, the gravitational collapse of the diskworld is completely ignored here.

the area of the upper surface of the disk is equal to the earth's surface area; Average density is equal to that of the earth. The depth of the disk is such that the vertical componet of the g field is as close to 9.81 (in most places) as possible. The gravitational collapse is ignored because the earth is assumed to have an unusually high tensile strength; I dont really see how the effect on the ocean and atmosphere can be ignored. Moreover, I plan to use the point where the centripetal force balances the g force as a "point of no return"

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can you try to explain better?

Comment: for a disk world, the gravitational field always has a horizontal component any point on the surface of the disk (except for the middle). This would cause the atmosphere and oceans to form a blob in the middle. one way of counteracting this horizontal component is to spin the earth, proving centrifugal force that opposes gravity. I want to know the optimum rotational speed. I can't do this myself as Idk how the gravitational field varies (numerically) across the surface in the first place.

Comment: Your question heavily depends on the abount of mass used for the world, as well as that it is magically strong enough to stay flat. It'll become a ball otherwise. Probably more, but I'm not an expert. What masses are you aiming for?

Comment: If you're ignoring the gravitational collapse of the disc itself, you may as well ignore the gravitational effect on the oceans and atmosphere, because that makes just as much sense.  (Additionally, unless the disc is particularly dense, I don't see any means for it to retain an atmosphere at all.)

Comment: the area of the upper surface of the disk is equal to the earth's surface area; Average density is equal to that of the earth. The depth of the disk is such that the vertical componet of the g field is as close to 9.81 (in most places) as possible. The gravitational collapse is ignored because the earth is assumed to have an unusually high tensile strength; I dont really see how the effect on the ocean and atmosphere can be ignored. Moreover, I plan to use the point where the centripetal force balances the g force as a "point of no return"

Comment: @jdunlop is right. The question assumes that *some* of the physics somehow continues to work when other parts have somehow stopped working. This is not logically consistent. You have a disc world, fine; but then just admit that gravitation works by magic and do not try to make it conform to the usual physics, because it won't work.

Comment: Which parts have stopped working? All I’ve assumed is that the earth has a high enough tensile strength to prevent gravitational collapse. If you don’t like that, you can assume orbital rings or something. I’m not simply ignoring valid physics here. I have an explanation for the stability of the disk that works with physics. If we were 100% consistent with physics, even a disk world existing is effectively impossible in the first place

Comment: So you want a disc with 9.81 G at the surface, you will end up with more living space on the rim of the disc than on the flats of the disc.

Comment: place the relevant info in the question, not in the comments

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica what relevant info? I have

Comment: the part I just edited into the question which you wrote in the comments, for example

Comment: Some elephants and a turtle on the bottom could have enough mass to make the gravity generally downward for the entire disc.

Answer (score 5):

It would depend on the material your diskworld is made of, thus how thick the disk has to be to generate acceptable surface gravity.

Unless your diskworld has some ludicrously dense baseplate, it will more resemble a cylinder-world. If made out of **roughly Earth-type materials (dense iron "core" for the gravity-producing mass below the surface**, then your diskworld will need to be 10000km thick.

In this case, the angle between the "flat" surface and the gravity gradient will not be very much at all, and a rather slow rotation can counter the gravity angle.

Surface equal to Earth surface area, projected on a flat circle: Radius = 12700km
Height of cylinder composed out of "earth" material, to cause gravity of 9.8 m/s^2 at centerpoint of the cylinder: ~ 10000km thick. Center of mass is thus 5000km below the surface.

At the extreme periphery of the disk, you are not 5000km away from CoM, but 13648km, thus gravity is only about 11/10 (due to shape not being sphere) of (5000/13648)^2 of the centerpoint gravity, thus about 3.9m/s^2.
This gravity is also at an angle of 68.5 degrees off vertical towards the centerpoint.

You need centrifugal force sufficient to make this gravity at the edge vertical.
The lateral part of the force is 3.9 * cos(21.5 degrees) = 3.63 m/s^2

You need to spin your disk/cylinder fast enough to generate 3.63 m/s^2 of centrifugal 'force' at a radius of 12700km
**This requires a rotational speed of 0.005056 rpm. (7.28 revolutions per 24-hours)**

Your diskworld now has mostly vertical "gravity" al over its surface, although that gravity does taper down from 9.8m/s^2 at the center down to 1.33m/s^2 at the edge.
And because the centrifugal force and gravity deviation only cancel out perfectly at the exact center and at the exact edge, your "flat" diskworld will need a vaguely bell-shaped surface to keep gravity and airpressure behaving reasonably. The surface needs to be about normal  (90 degrees) to my crudely-drawn gravity direction vectors.

Excuse the artwork, my drawing skills are closer to a drunk Picassso than to DaVinci
Also, will update the maff equations to look better once I figure out the interface for that.
[image]

P.S.
The *less* dense your supporting pillar is, the less the deviation becomes. If your cylinder is 10 times longer than it is wide, you can treat it as a cylindrical slice of a normal planet.
On the other hand, if you make a nice DENSE supermaterial for your gravity-inducing floor, you massively exacerbate the gravity angle problem!

I did the original calcs way, *way* back when I tried to figure a way past Pratchett's Discworld, and I came to the sound conclusion that gravity on the Discworld is provided by the mass of A'Tuin, augmented into a much smoother field by the masses of the Elephants: Berilia, Tubul, Great T'Phon, and Jerakeen, and not by the disc itself. From this viewpoint, the gravity and very slow rotation rate of that Discworld *actually makes numeric sense*.
(Although it does require A'Tuin to have an average density of more than 60g/c^3, three times denser than gold.

To mods: This mention of the proprietary work of the Author Pratchett is related only for comparison and background. If it violates rules, please remove it.

Comment: thankyou for these values. It appears my world will have to be a cylinder rather than a disk. Could you explain how you found the variation of the gravitational field across the surface? I've been trying to do it for age but have no idea how to do it analytically

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH The painful way.. A spreadsheet calculating incremental gravity on the edge of innumerable constant-density cylinders. it is *so* much easier with spheres or infinite cylinders, finite cylinders have really gronky math!!!

Comment: You just made a centrifugal pump, pumping all the atmosphere into outer space. Air which happens to be ouside the radius of the cylinder is being actively expelled outwards; and air is a fluid, it will flow towards the areas with smaller pressure.

Comment: @alexp well dUH, how does the air get over the rim wall, then? Surely you know that any self-respecting flat earth has a ginormous Rimwall that prevents people from falling off, flying over or otherwise disputing the edge of the world. A high enough Rimwall (a mere 120km will be ample) will stop any slosh from falling over the sides.

Comment: @alexp p.s. it would not pump it to outer space, but to the "belly" region of the cylinder. Which might be a good thing, as that location will be ***much*** more stable, maintainable and will not suffer from the horridly slanting gravity, leaky atmosphere, or other foibles of the flat(-ish) top of the discworld. Nice low-g environment, too.

Answer (score 0):

No solution exists.  Any given rotational velocity will produce one distance at which the gravity is counteracted, but you can't balance it everywhere.